# How to rotate a line in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Currently I need to rotate a line about the midpoint  based on angles generically. I have tried using Rotate Transform but it works finely for some angle but doest gives the exact result for some other angles. Kindly suggest if there any solution for rotation .

```
cx= (line.X1+line.2)/2;
cy=(line.Y1+line.Y2)/2;   
RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform();
transform.Angle = angle;
transform.CenterX = cx / zoomFactor;
transform.CenterY = cy / zoomFactor;
group.Children.Add(transform);
line.RenderTransform = group;
```

Comment: Please paste the actual code.

Comment: Do you have to do that transform from the code, or can you do it in the XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var cx = new Point( (line.X2 - line.X1)/2,  (line.Y2 - line.Y1) / 2);
  var rotate = new RotateTransform
  {
    Angle = angle
  };

  var translate = new TranslateTransform
  {
    X = (line.X1 + cx.X),
    Y = (line.Y1 + cx.Y)
  };
  var group = new TransformGroup
  {
    Children =
    {
      (Transform) translate.Inverse,
      rotate,
      translate
    }
  };

  line.RenderTransform = group;
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, instead of center.X I substituted cx.X.